# Sorting the report in birt

Tags: sorting, datetime, report, birt

I have created a column binding in a report(datetime column) using birt.
The datetime value that the column binding fetches based on the value of another string type column.
Now when I'm sorting the report based on the column binding, the result that I'm getting is initially sorted on the basis of the string column and then on the basis of the column binding.

I want the report to be sorted only on the basis of column binding (datetime) value.

Comment: Are you using a Computed Column for the date time?

Comment: No I'm not using the computed column...
The value of the datetime column is fetched on a simple if conditon...
ie if the values in string column is 'A' then fetch value from date1 column else if the value is 'B' then fetch value from date2 column in the column binding!!!!

Comment: Are you using 'order by' in you SQL?